# How to redirect the user back to the requested page after logging user in django?

Tags: django, redirect, authentication

I have been trying to develop a small app where some views require the user to be logged in. I am using method decorators to redirect the user to the login page. But after the user logs in he/she is redirected to the url defined in the success_url in my loginView. I want the user to be redirected to the page which the user was actually requesting.

Here is My LoginView

```
class LoginView(FormView):
template_name = 'draint_user/home.html'
form_class = LoginForm
# after login redirect users to the homepage again
success_url = '/artwork/upload'

def form_valid(self, form):
    login(self.request, form.user_cache)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

And here is the View that requires login

```
class LoginRequiredMixin(View):
@method_decorator(login_required)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class ArtworkUpload(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
template_name = 'artwork/artwork_upload.html'
form_class = ArtForm
success_url = 'list'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.draint_user = self.request.user
    print form.instance.draint_user
    artwork = form.save()
    result = super(ArtworkUpload, self).form_valid(form)
    return result
```

If the user is trying to view the ArtWorkUpload without logging in he is redirected to The LoginView. And after logging in I want him to be redirected to the ArtWorkUpload again.. Please suggest me some solutions .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

2 ways are:

- inspect `HTTP_REFERER` header
- provide a `next` param with your post request